# How does placing a barrier in an open channel affect the channel depth?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

Suppose you have an open channel with flowing water through it with a width $y$ and a the height of the water is $z$ at constant flowrate. If you were to place a barrier in the shape of a cuboid in the middle of the channel, where the width of the barrier, $w$, is less than the channel width i.e $w<y$. How would that affect the height of the water, $z$?

I've done the experiment at home so the relationship seems to be linear. I have used a pump to pump water to the top of the channel, using a reservoir with a rectangular hole cut into to distribute flow evenly. The open channel is rectangular.

Since flowrate is assumed to be constant, my initial though was to use the continuity equation; $v_1A_1=v_1A_2$. However since channel width is constant this can be further simplified to $v_1z_1=v_2z_2$.

Next I thought to apply bernoulli; $\frac{v^2}{2}+ gz + \frac{p}{\rho}=C$. Although im not really sure where to go from here, as instinctively I dont think pressure can be assumed to be constant. Attempting to substitute it into the continuity formula hasnt lead me anywhere either.

As for what I've looked at, I've looked at these studies which have similar experiments but they dont elaborate on the barrier width affecting the backwater profile, or I can't understand them if they do since admittedly this is definitely past the depths of my abilities. I've also looked at groynes as they do somewhat resemble the phenomenon im looking at. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/1090/1/012097/pdf, https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2006wr005267.

There is also this textbook which covers backwater profile in open channels slightly but I can't seem to make sense of it. It's on page 475. https://heidarpour.iut.ac.ir/sites/heidarpour.iut.ac.ir/files/u32/open-chow.pdf

I've also thought about using CFD software to model the flow. So far I've downloaded ANSYS student and set it up, but I can't seem to figure out how it works at all as its way beyond my depth.

All in all im not quite sure where to go from here. I've thought about assuming its orifice but that hasnt lead me anywhere. I thought about looking at literature about how dams affect water height but I havent found anything yet. Does anyone know of a principle or an idea which might get me to the next step?